# How to send an Email in a separate thread?

Tags: multithreading, email, c#-4.0

I was sending emails from my website fine, but Email part was slow, 
so I have decided to try and put this in a new thread, 
And came up with this

```
    public bool sendmail() 
    {
        Thread T1 = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            MailMessage eMail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"]);
            string EmailFromGCBS = (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFROM"]);

            eMail.From = new MailAddress(EmailFromGCBS);
            eMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailTo));
            eMail.Subject = emailSubject;
            eMail.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
            eMail.Body = emailBody;
            smtpClient.Send(eMail);

        });
        T1.Start();

        return true;
    }
```

the thread runs, but there is no emails sent any idea why this is?

Comment: Does the thread fail in any way?  Is it throwing an exception that isn't being caught by the main thread?  Can you debug this and confirm that `smtpClient.Send()` is completing without error?

Comment: I think it has to do with exception from `smtp`.Place a try catch inside your thread block.

Comment: Thanks I did add the try catch, which gave me a generic cant connect to server error.. The problem was with the SMTP server its self.